# How to POST a string and an image in one request using HttpClient?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, dotnet-httpclient, win-universal-app

I have a string and an image I need to `POST` to a web server using the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) in the Windows Runtime.

How can I post two things in one request using the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Easy! Try this:

```
using Windows.Web.Http;
using Windows.Web.Http.Headers;

private async void Foo()
{
    // the image
    var fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
    var streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(fileStream);
    var filename = "myImage.png";

    // the text
    var text = "oompa loompas";
    var stringContent = new HttpStringContent(text);

    // Putting all together.
    var formDataContent = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
    formDataContent.Add(streamContent, "myImage", fileName);
    formDataContent.Add(stringContent, "myString");

    // Send it to the server.
    var response = await (new HttpClient()).PostAsync(uri, formDataContent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For posting a string

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new StringContent(contentstring);
client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

For posting an image convert Image to stream and stream to string and the then httpcontent.

Comment: but how can we implement that to post StringContent and StreamContent simultaneously .I am need some help.

Comment: Can you please tell me briefly i cannot understand